# Mock react-router-dom useParams hook in vitest

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, create-react-app, vite, vitest

I just started to migrate from jest to vitest after migrating my app from cra to vite. I ran ainto an issue where I want to mock useParam hook of **react-router-dom**

Original code:

```
jest.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
  ...jest.requireActual('react-router-dom'), // use actual for all non-hook parts
  useParams: () => ({
    taskId: 123,
  }),
}));
```

I tried something like this:

```
vi.mock('react-router-dom', async () => ({
  ...vi.importActual('react-router-dom'), // use actual for all non-hook parts
  useParams: () => ({
    taskId: 123,
  }),
}));
```

But it's not working?

Answer (score 8):

I had the same problem, but this works perfect for me with correct TypeScript types

```
import { Params } from 'react-router-dom';

vi.mock('react-router-dom', () => ({
      useParams: (): Readonly<Params<string>> => ({ taskId: 123 }),
}));
```

Comment: This only works if I have a single test in the file.

How can I mock the return value for multiple tests?

Comment: @Borjante you can use a vi.mock in the before each and then it works. Or you can use spy on and run that before every test.

Comment: @LarsRijnen what do you mean by spying, could you give us an example?

Answer (score 4):

There is an example of the [cheatsheet](https://vitest.dev/guide/mocking.html) on mocking part of a module. This is what worked for me:

```
vi.mock('react-router-dom', async () => {
  const mod = await vi.importActual('react-router-dom');
  return {
    ...mod,
    useParams: () => ({
      taskId: 123,
    }),
  };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `__mocks__` folder with a `react-router-dom` mock as mentioned in the documentation: https://vitest.dev/api/vi.html#vi-mock.
Then do the mocking like this:

`__mocks__/react-router-dom.ts`:

```
import { vi } from 'vitest';

export * from 'react-router-dom';

export const useParams = vi.fn();
// .. add more mocks if needed
```

Then in your `*.test.tsx`

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

vi.mock('react-router-dom')

test("it mocks useParams()", () => {
  vi.mocked(useParams).mockReturnValue({ taskId: "123" });

  //...implement the tests

  expect(useParams).toHaveBeenCalled()
})
```

Comment: thanks, why the additional `vi.mock('react-router-dom')` in the test? 
I thought, that `vitest` automatically knows, that this is to be mocked, because it is within the `__mock__` directory?

Comment: If you worked with `jest` before, it does work that way, however it's not the case with `vitest`. It's mentioned in the documentation: https://vitest.dev/api/vi.html#vi-mock.
"Beware that if you don't call vi.mock, modules are not mocked automatically. To replicate Jest's automocking behaviour, you can call vi.mock for each required module inside setupFiles."

Comment: thanks -
kinda feels redundant, i mean, i already put it deliberately in the directory after all :D

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like:

```js
vi.mock('react-router-dom', async () => {
  return {
    ...vi.importMock('react-router-dom'),
    useHistory: vi.fn(),
    useParams: vi.fn(),
    useLocation: () => ({
      search: '',
      pathname: '/',
    }),
    matchPath: vi.fn(),
    withRouter: vi.fn(),
    useRouteMatch: vi.fn(),
    Link: ({ children, to }: { children: JSX.Element; to: string }) =>
      React.createElement('a', { href: to }, children),
    Router: () => vi.fn(),
    HashRouter: () => vi.fn(),
    Switch: () => vi.fn(),
  };
});
```

I think the reason why it fails is because the test code imports the real `react-router-dom` and the vi.mock is called, which in turn mocks the `react-router-dom`.

Mocking should take place before running actual tests.

Comment: Can you please explain how to mock a certain parameter which the component destructures from useParams()? I can't see it in your code.

Comment: An idea would be to try to re-mock the useParams inside the specific test.

Another approach is to parameterize useParams in the tested component and inject it with a mocked useParams in the test.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like this instead:

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

vi.mock('react-router-dom'

vi.mocked(useParams).mockReturnValue({ taskId: 123 })
```

Comment: There seem to be bugs here, can you please correct them?

Answer (score -1):

Upgrading to react-router-dom 6 solved all my previous mocking issues with vitest.

Migrating from v5 to v6 should be straightforward.